# Extracting name of layer in ArcGIS Pro project using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, layers

I am trying to use ArcPy to create a data catalog of ArcGIS Pro projects.

Does anyone know how to extract the actual name of a layer (the name in the GDB) not just the alias?

This is my code so far

```py
import arcpy
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"C:\Users\marco.conopio\Documents\MNL_07476032_ADM_Administrative\MNL_07476032_ADM_Administrative.aprx")
Maps=aprx.listMaps()[0]
for n in Maps.listLayers():
    print(n.name)
```

The output is just the name of the layer in the TOC but I also want the name of the layer in the GDB.

Comment: You've *asked* for the name of the layer, not the source.

Comment: yes i did. but i also want to asked for the name of the source. May I know what command should i use?

Comment: try `print (n.datasetName)`

Comment: Hi @GISDataButcher Thank you for the suggestion.

I tried to it and it gave me this error

AttributeError: 'Layer' object has no attribute 'datasetName'

Comment: @MarcoConopio what type layer it is? can you pls check it right click on layer it and paste path here

Comment: Hi @GISDataButcher
It is a Feature Class from a GDB. 
I did find a solution using 

` arcpy.Describe(n).name `

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the Layer documentation for [ArcGIS Pro](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/layer-class.htm) or [ArcMap](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm) (since there are differences) to see if one (or two in combination) of the following layer properties are what you're looking for. Also consider splitting the full path and taking only the final portion if you don't find what you're looking for.

##### **ArcGIS Pro Properties:**

**dataSource:** Returns the complete path for the layer's data source. It includes the full workspace path and name of the dataset. For enterprise geodatabase layers, a string containing the layer's connection information is returned.

**longName:** A layer's full name including group layer and composite layer structure.

**name:** The name of a layer the way it would appear in the table of contents. Spaces can be included. It is important that all layers in a map have a unique name so they can be easily referenced by their names.

##### **ArcMap Properties:**

**datasetName**: Returns the name of the layer's dataset the way it appears in the workspace, not in the TOC. Not all layers support the datasetName property (for example, web services), so it is good practice to test for this ahead of time using the supports method.

**dataSource**: Returns the complete path for the layer's data source. It includes the workspacePath and the datasetName properties combined. Not all layers support the dataSource property (for example, annotation classes and web services), so it is good practice to test for this ahead of time using the supports method.

**longName**: This property is valuable when trying to determine whether a layer belongs to a group layer. If a layer does not belong to a group layer, the long name will equal the layer name. If a layer does belong to a group layer, the group layer structure will be included in the long name. For example, the name of a layer nested inside a group layer within another group layer may look something like Group1\Group2\LayerName. All layer types support this property.

**name**: Provides the ability to set or get the name of a layer the way it would appear in the ArcMap table of contents. Spaces can be included. All layer types support this property.

**workspacePath**: Returns a path to the layer's workspace or connection file. Not all layers support the workspacePath property (for example, web services), so it is good practice to test for this ahead of time using the supports method.

Comment: Thank you for this.
The one I am looking for is the datasetName. Though it seems that this documentation is for Arcmap and not all commands are applicable in ArcGIS pro.
I tried to use datasetName and this error was shown

AttributeError: 'Layer' object has no attribute 'datasetName'